# How do I load a bytes object WAV audio file in torchaudio?

Tags: python, torch, torchaudio

I am trying to load a bytes-class object named "audio" to be loaded as a torchaudio object:

```
def convert_audio(audio, target_sr: int = 16000): 


    wav, sr = torchaudio.load(audio) 

    #(...) some other code
```

I cannot find any documentation online with instructions on how to load a bytes audio object inside Torchaudio, it seems to only accept path strings. But I have to save I/O in my application and I cannot write and load .wav files, only handle the audio objects directly.

Does anyone have a suggestion in this case?

If I use audio directly, I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.
  File "/home/felipe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 348, in _check_seekable
    f.seek(f.tell())
```

With BytesIO:

```
Exception has occurred: UnpicklingError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
invalid load key, '\x00'.
  File "/home/felipe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1002, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/felipe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 795, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/felipe/Coding projects/silero/stt.py", line 35, in convert_audio
    wav,sr = torch.load(io.BytesIO(audio))
  File "/home/felipe/Coding projects/silero/stt.py", line 60, in transcribe
    input = prepare_model_input(convert_audio(audio),
  File "/home/felipe/Coding projects/silero/psgui.py", line 97, in <module>
    transcripton = stt.transcribe('en',audio)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main (Current frame)
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's WAV format, `torchaudio.load` should be able to decode it from file-like object. Your code snippet looks good to me.

The following tutorial demonstrates it with different file-like objects.

https://pytorch.org/audio/0.13.0/tutorials/audio_io_tutorial.html#loading-from-file-like-object

Still, there are many reasons it does not work. For example, is your file-like object's cursor pointing the correct position (the beginning of the audio data)? Does the `read` method conformant to the [io.RawIOBase.read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) protocol?

It's hard to tell without seeing the error stacktrace.

Comment: Hello,

I am getting this error:

Exception has occurred: AttributeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.
  File "/home/felipe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 348, in _check_seekable
    f.seek(f.tell())

I will add to the main comment

Comment: You are using `torch.load`, which is different from `torchaudio.load`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to file-like object first

```
result = b'xxxxx'

# change result bytes stream to file-like object
wav_file_bytesIO = BytesIO(result)

data, sr = torchaudio.load(wav_file_bytesIO)
```

Comment: it causes `RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10a227560> and format None.`

Comment: the python I used is 3.9.17 and torchaudio2.0.2+cpu
Does your output look like: b'RIFF$\xd8\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00 ......'

Comment: Looks like this error caused because im not install ffmpeg. Sox cant work with streams.